How to properly refresh Google Cloud Python API credentials?
I'll re-formulate this question based on the feedback.
First, a few base facts:

I'm writing a GUI application that talks to google cloud services using the google.cloud Python SDK.
I'm using google oauth DeviceClient flow to sign in from a GUI application.
I'd like the user to sign in once, and then remember the sign-in persistently in device-local storage. Having to sign in again when re-starting the GUI application is not good enough.
I know how to run through the device flow, get the oauth response back, save it and reload it, and use it to create a credentials.Credentials object, and use this to create a google cloud client like storage.Client
I know that the client will attempt to re-refresh credentials when necessary as part of its internal work.

I previously believed that when using a refresh token to re-authorize, oauth returns a new refresh token that's not the same as the originally issued refresh token. I have verified that that's not actually the case here.
I believe that there is no good way to detect whether the storage.Client object has refreshed the credentials or not, nor do I believe that there is a good way to get the credentials back out from the client so I can introspect them and save the new refresh token for later use.
This is a problem, because if I re-create a new credentials.Credentials with the JSON I got back from the previous login, and then create a storage.Client from that token and refresh token, this client will blow up and claim it's not properly authorized. I then walk through the device login flow again, which generates a new oauth JSON payload, which works when I create a new client with these credentials. However, if I write that JSON payload to disk, re-start the program, re-load the JSON, and try to create a new credentials.Credentials from this JSON, the storage.Client created from those credentials no longer works; it claims I need to "re-login with gcloud auth" (which of course isn't the flow I use.)
My current theory is that the storage.Client re-creates a new authtoken, which invalidates the old authtoken, and when the program re-loads, the old authtoken saved to JSON is no longer valid, and rather than refreshing using the refresh token, the storage.Client simply throws. So, for this to work, I need to be able to store the current authtoken that the storage.Client ends up using, and there doesn't seem to be an accessor to read that back out.
This theory is strengthened, because the documentation for the token argument to Credentials says:
        token (Optional(str)): The OAuth 2.0 access token. Can be None
            if refresh information is provided.
        refresh_token (str): The OAuth 2.0 refresh token. If specified,
            credentials can be refreshed.

However, passing None for the token argument and passing in the proper refresh_token will immediately cause the storage.Client using the credentials to blow up when trying to refresh, with the following stack:
  File "videoripper/upload.py", line 157, in run
    blob.upload_from_filename(f)
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2959, in upload_from_filename
    self._handle_filename_and_upload(
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2829, in _handle_filename_and_upload
    self._prep_and_do_upload(
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2637, in _prep_and_do_upload
    created_json = self._do_upload(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2443, in _do_upload
    response = self._do_multipart_upload(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1956, in _do_multipart_upload
    response = upload.transmit(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py", line 153, in transmit
    return _request_helpers.wait_and_retry(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/_request_helpers.py", line 155, in wait_and_retry
    response = func()
               ^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py", line 145, in retriable_request
    result = transport.request(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 537, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 230, in before_request
    self._blocking_refresh(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 193, in _blocking_refresh
    self.refresh(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/oauth2/credentials.py", line 431, in refresh
    ) = reauth.refresh_grant(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/oauth2/reauth.py", line 348, in refresh_grant
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: Reauthentication is needed. Please run `gcloud auth application-default login` to reauthenticate.


The credentials have not expired; they were minted just a few moments ago. Passing in the authtoken returned by the device auth flow, makes this work, once -- but the next attempts, even if it's just moments later, fail with this same stack trace.
The code I'm using is as follows (copy-paste-assembled from a few functions):
import json
from oauthlib.oauth2 import DeviceClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from google.cloud import storage

# Constants
CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'GOCSPX-xxxxx'
SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write']

# URLs for device and token requests
device_auth_url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/device/code'
token_url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'

try:
    with open("/opt/store/creds.json", "w") as f:
        stored = json.load(f)
        creds = credentials.Credentials(
            stored['access_token'],
            refresh_token=stored['refresh_token'],
            token_uri=oa.token_url,
            client_id=oa.CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=oa.CLIENT_SECRET)
        gclient = storage.Client(project=PROJECT, credentials=creds)
        gclient.list_buckets()
        # it worked
        return stored
except Exception as e:
    # it didn't work
    pass
client = DeviceClient(client_id=CLIENT_ID)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
device_auth_response = oauth.post(device_auth_url, data={
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': ' '.join(SCOPE)
})
darj = device_auth_response.json()
device_code = darj['device_code']
user_code = darj['user_code']
verification_url = darj['verification_url']

print(f"Please visit {verification_url} and paste the code: {user_code}", flush=True)

# now wait for the user to go through the flow, polling for success
token_response = oauth.post(token_url, data={
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    'device_code': device_code,
    'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code'
})
if token_response.status_code == 200:
    # Successfully retrieved the token
    token = token_response.json()
    with open("/opt/store/creds.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(token, f)
    return token
raise Exception("Computer says no.")

As an additional challenge, when I try the creds.refresh call, I get an error that credentials have expired, even if I just got them back from logging in.
>>> creds.refresh(requests.Request())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/oauth2/credentials.py", line 431, in refresh
    ) = reauth.refresh_grant(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/oauth2/reauth.py", line 348, in refresh_grant
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: Reauthentication is needed. Please run `gcloud auth application-default login` to reauthenticate.

This happens even when the credentials themselves work fine.

please edit your question and include the code you are using to get the access token and refresh token.  currently i can not see how you are getting it nor how you are testing to see if the access token has expired, nor where you are refreshing it once it has expired.

I updated the question to be clearer about expectations versus questions.
Also, I have written a script that goes from A-Z on reproducing the behaviors I think are unexpected or not matching documentation. You can find it here:
https://gist.github.com/jwatte/e46c4bfd0e4cfd5238dbff3d68f65072
You'll need to set up a google cloud project and oauth device flow app to use it, though.

Currently i can see nothing in your code that tests if the token has expired nor where you are attempting to refresh it once it has.
if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
      creds.refresh(Request())


How do I get the new refresh token back out of the library, so I can store it, such that the user doesn't need to log in again when they next start up the application?

The only way to get a refresh token is to request authorization of the user. Refresh tokens are long lived they do not expire unless under some specific circumstances. see experation

If your refresh token has expire the only way to get a new one is to prompt the user for consent again.

Thank you for your answer. I'm confused by this though:
"Refresh tokens are long lived they do not expire unless under some specific circumstances"
Security best practices say that refresh tokens are expired (and replaced with a new refresh token) each time they're actually used to create an access token. This way, I will know if someone else stole my refresh token. Are you saying that the Google auth platform does not implement this?

You can have UpTo 100 outstanding refresh tokens they will all work.  You need them in the event the user grants access on more than one device.   A stolen refresh token is useless without the client is and client secret that creates it.  I'm saying no oauth2 platform does what you are saying


A stolen refresh token is useless without the client is and client secret that creates it.

As I'm sure you know, the Device Flow encodes the client "secret" on the device, meaning, it is under the control of any owner of a similar device. For example, if I have a TV that logs into Google Cloud, I can easily get the client secret for this TV from disassembling the firmware.
